# Blue Giga C++ anti-corruption layer for C callback API?

Tags: object-oriented, c++, c, callbacks

I'm working with a Blue Giga BLE112 usb dongle. They supply an API in the form of several header & *.c files. It all works off of callbacks. For example.

```
int main()
{
    // defined in a "cmd_def.h" & implemented in "cmd_def.c"
    ble_cmd_connection_get_status();

    // read messages off the usb serial port forever
    // At some point, we'll read the message that triggers the connection status event.
    while (true) { readMessages(); }
}

// Call back that we implement
void ble_evt_connection_status(const struct ble_msg_connection_status_evt_t *msg)
{
    // This is terrible because we could call the command from anywhere 
    // and have no idea what context the event is firing under 
    // with no way to pass any information into the callback except from global state.

    if (msg->flags & connection_connected) 
    {
        printf("WE'RE CONNECTED!);
    }
}
```

There are around 100 or so pairs of these `Command`s and `responseEventCallback`s.

Now, I'm trying to implement a small C++ console application, but I'm having an extremely hard go of it. I've been trying to wrap this behavior in a C++ class, but am failing miserably. At each and every turn I run into issues trying to use these callbacks to set state in the class. (Obviously, I can't because the callbacks are static and can't access *members* of the class.)

Was this a misguided idea? I thought that if I could introduce an OO anti-corruption layer, I could make it easier to deal with the global state and  callback hell I've found myself in.

Does anyone have any insight into how to cleanly implement this kind of C callback API in C++? I'm staring at all these callbacks thinking that this is going to be a nightmare to maintain, but I'm also unable to figure out how to wrap these command/response events into a class.

Would it be better to simply forget the classes and implement this as a "module" of functions?

For reference, here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
// nice clean OO api

bool scanning = false;

BLUEGIGA_API bool BlueGiga::IsConnected()
{
    _isConnected = false;

    ble_cmd_connection_get_status(0);
    scanning = true;

    while (scanning)
    {
        if (!ReadMessage())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return _isConnected;
}

// C callback that should not be part of my C++ api, nor can it be a member because C can't use C++ members as callbacks.

void ble_evt_connection_status(const struct ble_msg_connection_status_evt_t *msg)
{
    // _isConnected isn't identified because we don't have a `this` instance in here.
    _isConnected = (msg->flags & connection_connected);

    scanning = false;
}
```

Comment: I would probably make a singleton class connect to all these callbacks and work your way from there.

Comment: I cannot see whether the C callback allows you to hold some sort of private context (that you could make to point to your instance) - that should be somewhere in `msg`, itf at all. If it doesn't, its probably badly designed and you should refrain from trying to wrap it into a class.

Comment: @tofro I'm gonna go with "it's badly designed". There's no context. If we decide to use the hardware beyond this prototype, I'm going to need to re-implement their protocol parser. I think I found a way to get the code under test, but it involves making changes to the files that Blue Giga provides.

Comment: I have an idea of how to do this.  I am assuming that the callback function must be named that specific name.  You could do it the same way that Win32++ calls CreateWindowEx: keep a map of function pointer to this pointer so that when the callback gets called it can look up the callback in the map and get the this pointer.  I will try to find time to write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're not only getting the API into an object-oriented way but you want to transform it into a synchronous API from an asynchronous API ?

Doesn't seems like a good idea to me if it has been made like this, there might be some reason while you should not change it.

C++ API with callbacks are nothing unseen and nothing incompatible with OOP, you can find them in boost Asynchronous networking library (Boost ASIO : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), may be looking a little in will give you some idea.

Note : Reading boost headers might be a bit difficult.

In the end i think you should keep the asynchronous way in OOP. This is surely doable using some not so obivous syntax but i don't know which one.

And for the design of your application, think about how UI works generally, you usually have one thread for the UI, one (or more) for the rest, i guess that the best way to go. The "UI thread" will lock any new command while the current one is processed, he will then print the result and ask for a new command. UI Thread will be callbacked by the API running in the other.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you will only do one of each kind of request at a time you could keep a map of callback function to this pointer.  I think this is your use case because you are looping on ReadMessage inside of each command function.  Perhaps something kind of like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>

// provided by the library - somehow

const int connection_connected = 0x01;
struct ble_msg_connection_status_evt_t { int flags; } msg = {0xFF};
void ble_evt_connection_status(const struct ble_msg_connection_status_evt_t *msg);
void ble_cmd_connection_get_status(int) { }
bool ReadMessage() { ble_evt_connection_status(&msg); return true; }

// provided by you

struct BlueGiga;

std::map<void*,BlueGiga*> this_finder; // this could be in thread local storage...

struct BlueGiga
{
    bool IsConnected()
    {
        _isConnected = false;

        this_finder.insert(std::make_pair((void*)::ble_evt_connection_status,this));

        ble_cmd_connection_get_status(0);

        _scanning = true;

        while (_scanning)
        {
            if (!ReadMessage())
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return _isConnected;
    }

    void ble_evt_connection_status(const struct ble_msg_connection_status_evt_t *msg)
    {
        _isConnected = (msg->flags & connection_connected);
        _scanning = false;
    }

    int _isConnected;
    bool _scanning;
};

int main()
{
    BlueGiga blueGiga;
    return blueGiga.IsConnected();
}

// one for every callback - could use a macro to make it easier

void ble_evt_connection_status(const struct ble_msg_connection_status_evt_t *msg)
{
    BlueGiga* object = this_finder[(void*)::ble_evt_connection_status];
    object->ble_evt_connection_status(msg);
}

/* sample macro

#define DECLARE_CALLBACK(func,param) \
void func(const struct param *msg) \
{ \
    BlueGiga* object = this_finder[(void*)::func]; \
    object->func(msg); \
}

DECLARE_CALLBACK(ble_evt_connection_status,ble_msg_connection_status_evt_t)

*/
```